# UWP Xaml Internal Error 'WMC9999' Cannot find type System.Web.HttpException in module System.Web.dll

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml

Every time i try to test my App in Visual Studio (2022) i get this Build Error:

```
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.19041.0\XamlCompiler\Microsoft.Windows.UI.Xaml.Common.targets(410,5): Xaml Internal Error error WMC9999: Cannot find type System.Web.HttpException in module System.Web.dll.
```

A minimal reproducible example is in [this GitHub Repository](https://github.com/Promlg1104/Example-of-UWP-Error)

Thanks in advance for any Help
PS: I'm very new to C# and only know the Basics

Comment: I have run above http request code, it works well without exception, this is in fact an error in one of your XAML. could you share [mcve] for us?

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT First thanks for your Answer!
I was trying lots of things and came up with this:
The Error only Appears when i'm using the [Microsoft.AspNet.WebHelpers](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebHelpers/) Package with Visual Studios Packet Manager and use System.Web.Helpers.Json.Decode() Function (I need Json Decode to Decode the Result from the Http Request) so i think the Error is caused by that but i dont know how to Decode Json in other ways

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT as Requested i made a minimal reproducible example and uploaded it on Github in [this Repository](https://github.com/Promlg1104/Example-of-UWP-Error)

Comment: I have replied the answer below, you need to remove this nuget and decode json string with `Windows.Data.Json` or Newtonsoft library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The Error only Appears when i'm using the Microsoft.AspNet.WebHelpers Package

This is AspNet nuget package, it is not compatible with UWP platform. For decode json string, you could use `Windows.Data.Json` to deserialize json string, and here is official [code sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/main/Samples/Json) that you could refer to.

And you could also use third part library to deserialize json string, such as Newtonsoft.